# Trace of inverse from LU decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, lapack, dense-matrix

Given an LU decomposition of $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, is there a way to compute $\operatorname{trace}(A^{-1})$ with lower complexity than that of the inversion ($O(n^3)$ in practice)?

This question has been asked already on [Mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/46553/fast-trace-of-inverse-of-a-square-matrix) [twice](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/163414/numerical-trace-of-inverse-matrix-from-cholesky) and on [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/391128/trace-of-an-inverse-matrix), but the answers there are not useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base case: Computing the factorization requires $\frac 2 3n^3$ operations and the inverse requires $\frac 4 3n^3$ operations. Computing the trace adds $O(n)$. Let's round that to $2n^3$.

LU case: Computing the factorization requires $\frac 2 3n^3$ operations. If you were to compute $L^{-1}$ and $U^{-1}$, those operations each require $\frac 1 3n^3$ operations. The trace of the matrix product $U^{-1}L^{-1}$ is essentially a dot product of two vectors with length $n^2$, call that $O(n^2)$. Let's round that to $\frac 4 3n^3$.

Asymptotically, you're no better off. But, you can calculate the trace with approximately 33% fewer operations.

Source: https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/mkl-developer-reference-fortran/top/lapack-routines/lapack-linear-equation-routines/lapack-linear-equation-computational-routines.html

Comment: Good call. I edited my answer to include the factorization time for inversion. Fundamentally, inverting a triangular matrix is still $O(n^3)$, and you need every coefficient of $L$ and $U$ to compute the trace. However, reducing the run time of your routine by 30 or 50% is definitely worth the effort, even if you can't change the asymptotic behavior!